# Java UI communication between threads

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, runnable

I am trying to create a game with a UI Thread so that it can update without waiting for the game logic to complete. Currently I am doing this with a Runnable class Game like so (stripped down code):

```
public class Game implements Runnable {
    GameView gameView;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.start();
    }

    public void start() {
        Thread t = new Thread(this, "UIThread");
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        //Adding views here
        gameView = new GameView();
        gameView.setActionListener(this);
    }

    public doAction() {
        gameView.updateSomething();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        doAction();
    }
}
```

The run() method and GameView construction occurs in the new thread as expected and actionPerformed() happens on the main thread which I want (though i am not sure why it does). The issue I am having is that when I try to call a method on gameView in doAction() the gameView method runs on the main thread. How can I tell the gameView object to do something on the new thread instead?

Comment: How would I do that? Is gameView not running in the new thread if i created it from the new thread?

Comment: You code sample is a little light on details, just because the object is created within a thread, doesn't make that object "run" within that thread, it can be accessed from many different threads.  If you want work to be performed on the "other" thread, you need some way to transfer information between them, may a queue for example.  The "thread" waits until something is the queue and pulls it out and takes action on.  The "UI" posts "actions" to the queue which it wants executed. This is a basic [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer (first comment) ...what? Objects don't run on threads.

Comment: @immibis Yeah I was thinking about something else.  For example, a `Queue` which is processed from a separate queue...brain hasn't quite woken up yet....

Comment: @MadProgrammer many thanks, I will look into using a queue.

Comment: You may be better off with the Executor framework than using runnable directly